# Delete Lines containing a string after a Matching patterns?

Tags: shell, sed

In my yaml file , i want to delete a block using Sed After matching a pattern .

**Example:**

```
Keypages:
- name: Key pages
LaunchPad:
- name: "\U0001F680Launch Pad"
- location: US
Microservices:
- name: 'Micro services '
```

In this example , when matching **LaunchPad**(for example) in the start of a line, i want to delete it ans its block ( for me the lines  starting with **-** and then stop when not finding **-**)

Result :

```
Keypages:
- name: Key pages
Microservices:
- name: 'Micro services '
```

thank you

Comment: I don't think this is possible with something like `sed`, which processes line by line, you might need to write a python script or something that can handle this kind of file modification on your own

Comment: I'd suggest to use tools that understand yaml, like https://github.com/TomWright/dasel for example

Comment: Welcome on StackOverflow. Please show what you tried up to now and explain why it did not work as expected. Alternately, you could take a look at the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) and especially at the [asking section](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking).

Answer (score 0):

Use this Perl one-liner:

```
perl -i.bak -ne 'print unless m{^LaunchPad} .. !m{^\s*-}' in_file
```

The Perl one-liner uses these command line flags:
`-e` : Tells Perl to look for code in-line, instead of in a file.
`-n` : Loop over the input one line at a time, assigning it to `$_` by default.
`-i.bak` : Edit input files in-place (overwrite the input file). Before overwriting, save a backup copy of the original file by appending to its name the extension `.bak`.

`EXPR1 .. EXPR2` : this is true in between where expression EXPR1 is true and expression `EXPR2` is true, inclusive.

`!m{^\s*-}` : **not** matching a pattern where the line starts with 0 or more whitespace characters followed by a dash.

**SEE ALSO:**
[`perldoc perlrun`: how to execute the Perl interpreter: command line switches](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#Command-Switches)
[`perldoc perlre`: Perl regular expressions (regexes)](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html)
[`perldoc perlre`: Perl regular expressions (regexes): Quantifiers; Character Classes and other Special Escapes; Assertions; Capture groups](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Regular-Expressions)
[`perldoc perlrequick`: Perl regular expressions quick start](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrequick)

Answer (score 0):

Using the python [PyYaml library](http://pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAMLDocumentation), you can use the following script as a filter that removes any section named `LaunchPad`:

```py
import sys, yaml
data = yaml.safe_load(sys.stdin)
del data['LaunchPad']
yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)
```

Simply run: `python above-script < input.yml > output.yml`

Given this input:

```yaml
Keypages:
- name: Key pages
LaunchPad:
- name: "\U0001F680Launch Pad"
- location: US
Microservices:
- name: 'Micro services '
```

The above script produces this output:

```yaml
Keypages:
- {name: Key pages}
Microservices:
- {name: 'Micro services '}
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -n '/^LaunchPad:/{:a;n;/^-/ba};p' file
```

Turn off implicit printing `-n`.

Match a line beginning `LaunchPad:` and then fetch following lines beginning with `-`.

Print all other lines.

Alternative:

```
sed '/LaunchPad:/{:a;N;/^-/Ms/\n//;ta;D}' file
```